# Linked list not functioning properly

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, linked-list, malloc

I am creating a linked-list type data structure but not exactly. I have the following so far, but the problem is, only the first link persists after this method is done, the links after the first one go away. What is the issue here?

```
//Global Vars
m_p H = NULL; //m_p is the struct

func(){
    /* .... */
    H = malloc(sizeof(m_r));
    H->next = NULL;
    H->previous = NULL;
    m_p p = H;
    for(i = 0; i < nLists; i++){
        m_p n = malloc(sizeof(m_r));
        n->next = NULL;
        n->previous = p;
        p->next = n;

        p = p->next;
    }
  //if I iterate through the links here, they all print out fine

  m_p x = H;
  while(x != NULL){
     printf("%d ", x->data);
     x = x->next;
  }
}
```

Since H is a global variable, shouldn't the links stay as is? When I try to loop through the links in another function in the same file, they aren't present, only the first one is. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: I have omitted the part where i am setting the data field in each struct to keep code concise.

Edit 2: Here is a function in another file, and this is where the error occurs:

```
extern m_p H;

m_p func2(int s) {

  int n_s = ALIGN(s);
    m_p p = H;

    while(p != NULL ){
        printf("1. %d \n", p->data);
        p = p->next; //this is always NULL even if there were more than one node previously in func()
        if(p == NULL) printf("LINK NOT PRESENT \n");    
    }

  /* ... */

}
```

Also this is what my struct looks like:

```
typedef struct m{
    struct m *next;
    struct m *previous;
    int data;

} m_r, *m_p;
```

Comment: oops, i made an error while trying to retype this. @BLUEPIXY

Comment: This is what my code looks like; it still gives the error. @BLUEPIXY

Comment: The error still persists @BLUEPIXY

Comment: `previous ` of the first node and `next` of the last node are not set.

Comment: Even if they arent, why would that create a problem if I am only using the next pointers to iterate through to print out the data?

Comment: please post the code in `func()` for printing the list... maybe the problem is there

Comment: @TirthRami In the case of _only using the next pointers_,  You do not know the end of the list.

Comment: I have added the code for printing @cbuchart maybe that will shed some light

Comment: `while(x != NULL){` This will check if the current node is `NULL`. But Where did you set `NULL`?

Comment: Provide  [mcve]. Add part of setting of `x->data` too.

Comment: It seems that the current code will work as expected. [DEMO](http://ideone.com/uxGMgS) If there is a problem, it is different from the actual code or there is a problem in another place.

Comment: Could it perhaps be an issue that the other function is in another file? I Upon further testing, the linked list is fine in another function in the same file, but when I call another function in a different file that is when the other links seem to go away. I added more information to the post as well. @BLUEPIXY

Comment: `m_p *H = NULL;` --> `m_p H = NULL; `

Comment: Didn't fix it, what else should I include to help solve this issue? @BLUEPIXY

Comment: Since your code differs every time I see it, I can not say anything certain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, your code looks fine. The code that BLUEPIXY provided works, so I would have to agree with BLUEPIXY. Your problem is probably elsewhere. This is the code I tested on my computer (which is very similar to [BLUEPIXY's code](http://ideone.com/uxGMgS)).

**list.h**

```
struct node {
    struct node *previous, *next;
    int data;
};

void linkedList();
void anotherFunction();
void freeMemory();
```

**list.c**

```
#include <stdlib.h> // malloc, free
#include <stdio.h> // printf
#include "list.h"

// Global variable
struct node *m_root;

void linkedList(){
    m_root = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    m_root->data = -1;
    m_root->next = NULL;
    m_root->previous = NULL;
    int i;
    int n = 10;
    struct node *prev = m_root;
    struct node *next;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        next = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        next->data = i;
        next->previous = prev;
        prev->next = next;

        prev = prev->next;
    }

    printf("Within linkedList\n");
    struct node *iter = m_root;
    while(iter!=NULL){
        printf("%d ",iter->data);
        iter = iter->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void anotherFunction(){
    printf("Within anotherFunction\n");
    struct node *iter = m_root;
    while(iter!=NULL){
        printf("%d ",iter->data);
        iter = iter->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void freeMemory(){
    printf("Freeing memory\n");
    struct node *current = m_root;
    struct node *next;
    while(next!=NULL){
        next = current->next;
        free(current);
    }
    m_root->next = NULL;
    m_root = NULL;
}
```

**extern.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "list.h"

extern struct node *m_root;

void anotherFileFunction(){
    struct node *iter = m_root;
    while(iter!=NULL){
        printf("1. %d\n",iter->data);
        iter = iter->next;
    }
}

int main(){
    linkedList();
    anotherFileFunction();
    freeMemory();
    anotherFileFunction();
    printf("Done!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Output is:

```
Within linkedList
-1 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
1. -1
1. 0
1. 1
1. 2
1. 3
1. 4
1. 5
1. 6
1. 7
1. 8
1. 9
Freeing memory
Done!
```

Comment: Could it perhaps be an issue that the other function is in another file? I Upon further testing, the linked list is fine in another function in the same file, but when I call another function in a different file that is when the other links seem to go away.